# Prove that $\forall \ n \in \mathbb{N}, \ n^2 + 3n + 2$ is not prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Can anyone explain step by step how to use direct proof for solve this type of sum. Seriously I am confused with direct proof.

Comment: Have you tried factorizing the expression?

Comment: Actually i don't know how to approach this type of a sum.

Comment: That is quadratic equation, even if you can't guess the solution, you should be able to calculate the roots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try factoring $n^2 + 3n + 2$. You get $(n+1)(n+2)$. Observe that since we deal with only positive numbers, none of $n+1$ or $n+2$ is equal to 1. Prime numbers are those numbers which do not have any factors other than $1$ and itself. But $n^2 + 3n + 2$ has two factors namely $n+1$ and $n+2$. So it is not a prime.

Since you asked for a direct proof I will suggest another proof. Consider that for all odd and even integers that number $n^2 + 3n + 2$ is even. The function is strictly increasing and the lowest value for $n=1$ turns out to be $6$. We know that all even numbers greater than $6$ are composite.

Comment: I know find factors for the expression. but I don't understand how to apply direct proof theories for this proof. :(

Comment: @Rohit Edited the answer. Hope you understand that.

Comment: ok i can understand the proof. but the questions says prove this using direct proof. so what is the direct proof means? how should I apply it to solve this sum?

Comment: @Rohit I have extended the answer to prove this directly without any algebraic manipulation.

Comment: can you please explain how to solve this using algebraic manipulations.

Comment: @Rohit The first answer uses algebraic manipulation. The second one is a direct proof.

Answer (score 0):

hint: $n^2+3n+2=(n+1)(n+2)$.is it clear?

Comment: yeah.. surely. know factorizing.

Answer (score 0):

If $n$ is even, $n^2$ is even and $3n$ is even, thus$n^2+3n+2$ is even and hence not prime.
If $n$ is odd, $n^2$ is odd and  $3n$ is odd, thus $n^2+3n+2$ is again divisible by 2.